# Getting issue during Login in <iframe> using Hybrid Auth

Tags: php, iframe, hybridauth

I have successfully integrated the Hybrid Social Auth api (https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth).
Problem is that when some one want to create iframe of my website to their own website then it creates problem during login.
Is there any solution ?

Comment: What kind of problem does it create ?

Comment: Showing below error at console -> Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=some_api_key…ser_denied8dfd4c9%2XX988_%_&display=page' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'

Comment: You have to change the `X-Frame-Options` value.

Comment: From where I can change ?

Comment: Its value is set at the server side, Facebook set its value to deny so that it wont open any other domain origins except its own. This [link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers) might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

`iframes` and `frames` around bound by the `X-Frame-Options` header to prevent [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking). You'll want to make sure this is set to `SAMEORIGIN` or something that will allow the content to render inside a frame. you should be fine as long as it's not `DENY`.

if you do not control the server of the page you are trying to frame, then you are being blocked by them for security reasons.